# Rank of matrices multiplication

Tags: matrices, finite-fields

Matrices $m_1$ and $m_2$ are over a finite field($GF(2^{8})$ for example).

$m_1$ is a $m\times n$ matrix($n > m$) with $rank(m_1) = m$,

and $m_2$ is a $n\times c$ ($c > n > m$) matrix with $rank(m_2) = n$.

$m_3 = m_1 \cdot m_2$ and the multiplication is over the same finite field.

My question is that is rank of $m_3$ alway equals to $m$? Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.  Let $F$ be the field.  Then $m_1$ corresponds to a surjective linear function from $F^n$ to $F^m$, and $m_2$ corresponds to a surjective linear function from $F^c$ to $F^n$.  The composition of surjective functions is surjective, so $m_3=m_1m_2$ must be a surjective linear function from $F^c$ to $F^m$.  It follows that $m_3$ has rank $m$.

Comment: And as far as I can tell, this did not depend on $F$ being finite.

Comment: @FrankMcGovern This is true.  The OP asked about a finite field, but I'll change my answer to reflect the generality.

Comment: You mean that this property is satisfied whether the matrix is over a finite field or not? @FrankMcGovern

Comment: @foool Yes, the only thing we needed was the composition of surjective maps is surjective.

Comment: @FrankMcGovern  Thanks!

Comment: @JimBelk Could you help me with this question please http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/669018/rank-of-quadratic-form